# Android Scaling Image

Tags: android, imageview, scale

I have a `Relative layout` whose height is fixed - `356 px` and width is wrap content.
I have placed an `Imageview` with background as image .
The image dimensions are `496 px * 496 px`.

The image is a square image but getting scaled as a rectangle . 
Here is the `XML`-

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/rlMain"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="356px" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivIcon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/outdoor_verygood_ring" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is how the original image is - [image]

Here is how it looks in the Relative layout -

[image]

What i want is - if the image is getting scaled it should `get scaled in both X and Y` .
How can i achieve this ?

Comment: try with `android:src`

Comment: You can set image width and hight dynamically means using code

Comment: @MMohsinNaeem : You are great. Can you please explain me why the scaling is happening correct in case of src attribute.

Comment: plz use dimension in dp because that is set as per different density device. px will remain same for all devices.

Comment: @SanketKachhela :Thanks for suggestion to  use dimensions in dp . But this question is resolution specific. I am designing my app for just one resolution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`src` never change the aspect ratio. it displays the image as it is. by leaving extra space around the Image view.

On he other hand `background` try to fill the full background of the `ImageView`. As you give the `constant` height and width with `wrap_content`. So in your case first it wraps the width and then apply the height. which is obviously wrong.

In you case if you want 1:1 ratio you can give the fix width and height. where `width=height`.

But in general if you want any aspect ratio to maintain then you can use  `src` attribute.

and

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

is a magical line.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the aspect ratio of the image properly. In your case anyway try different options given for `imageview.scaleType`. Follow [this link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html) below to set proper option for you in xml:

May be in you case try:

```
android:scaleType= "CENTER_INSIDE" for imageview
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix this

From

```
android:background="@drawable/outdoor_verygood_ring"
```

To

```
android:src="@drawable/outdoor_verygood_ring"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

Background is resized based on the widget placement and its properties. The src, is within the ImageView and is controlled by the ImageView properties. No ImageView property controls the background.